# Flutter Button is not cooparates with simple code

Tags: flutter, dart, button, width, box

my goal is to define width of **ElevatedButton**, i tried to include Button in **SizedBox** as in **Container**, now its in **ConstrainedBox** and its still not working, its streched on entire length of app and i want him to have **width: 100.0** Thx in advance

````
ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(
                  width: 60.0,
                  height: 60.0,
                ),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Blabla"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("Yup");
                  },
                ),
              ),```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmgj5.png
````

Comment: It is inside a stretched Column?

Comment: It's inside Column

Comment: Not the best way, but something that solves it is to use ```Padding```, on the left and right side of the button, but only if it is stretched, this way will shrink in both sides.

Comment: When you use ```crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch``` even if you wrap the button with a ```Container``` it will stretch.

Comment: padding is working, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Padding()`to define the desired width :

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print("Je suis une coquine");
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 16.0, top: 4.0, right: 16.0, bottom: 4.0),
              child: Text("blabla"),
            ),
          )
```